# Is BB-8's name inspired by BB ammunition?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, droids, bb-8

The distinguishing feature of BB-8's design compared to other astromechs is his spherical body, whereas previously seen astromechs generally have a cylindrical body.

## Was the name inspired by [BB ammunition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BB_gun), which is also distinctively spherical?

[image]
[image]

[image]   << R-series astromechs for comparison

Comment: (This is presumably an out-of-universe question unless there is something very surprising out there.)

Comment: Or instead of BB ammunition, it looks like a BasketBall, or a Bowling Ball, or a Ball Bearing?

Comment: I find it amusing that the R series goes back and forth between a half-sphere top dome and a truncated cylinder. 2,3,7,9 are clearly half-spheres while 4, 5, 6 are clearly truncated cylinders, with 1 and 8 being somewhat in between.

Comment: @Draco18s:   *truncated cone

Comment: @ThePopMachine FFS, yes, that shape.  `*`grumbles something about graduating college and forgetting Math`*`

Comment: @ThePopMachine perhaps you mean the frustum of a cone?

Comment: @MattGutting, what did you call me?!  But seriously,  interesting term, but Google image search tells me both terms are used.

Comment: Since you're question is about BB-8, do we really need an image of the "R-series astromechs for comparison"?

Comment: @RedCaio, it is justifying the claim that "previously seen astromechs generally have a cylindrical body".  Absent that, the question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 12):

Seems unlikely.

*Entertainment Weekly* interviews J.J. Abrams about the movie, and [asked him about the inspiration behind some of the character names](http://www.ew.com/article/2015/08/12/star-wars-force-awakens-character-names/). According to him, the design came first and the name came from that:

> Abrams chose the droid's name because it looked round and bouncy. "I named him BB-8 because it was almost onomatopoeia," the director says. "It was sort of how he looked to me, with the 8, obviously, and then the 2 B's."

It's not beyond the realm of possibility that the *design* of BB-8 was inspired by BB ammunition, thus making the name indirectly inspired by it, but it does seem somewhat unlikely. According to [an article on StarWars.com](http://www.starwars.com/news/droid-dreams-how-neal-scanlan-and-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens-team-brought-bb-8-to-life), the design came from Abrams himself:

> When it came time to create a new astromech droid for the first film of a new *Star Wars* trilogy, director J.J. Abrams started as anyone might: he made a sketch on a napkin. It’s a fitting beginning, considering the handmade, warm look and feel of *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*. The sketch was basic — two circles atop one another, with a tiny dot for an eye

Although I'm not sure of explicit confirmation, it's commonly believed that the design inspiration for BB-8 came from one of Ralph McQuarrie's early concepts for R2-D2; [a Slashfilm article](http://www.slashfilm.com/ralph-mcquarrie-force-awakens/) quotes the artist as saying:

> I think Artoo was just described as a small robot. I thought of him as running on a giant ball bearing — just a sphere, a circle, wheel-like. He had gyros so he could go in any direction on this ball.

[image]

Comment: *It was sort of how he looked to me, with the 8* so far so good *and then the 2 Bs* wow that was sudden and unexplained why not AA xD

Comment: @yondaime008:   I believe what he means is that a B looks like an 8 (looks like BB-8).

Comment: @ThePopMachine yea i thought about that too later, what can I say, i'm slow minded ._.

Comment: Note that Abrams used the word onomatopoeia incorrectly.  He meant autologlyph - the typographical concept of a written word made to look like the concept it represents.  In this case the letter B and the number 8 look like the droid design.

Comment: Yeah. The onomatopoeia (sounds written out as words (e.g. blam, whoosh, etc)) comment kinda threw me too. Made me think of the "beedeebeedee" sounds from Twiki, the robot from the Buck Rogers TV show.

Comment: @Kai This isn't really an autologlyph either. An autologlyph is something akin to a work of art, twisting the physical appearance of a specific, fixed piece of writing in one way or another to give it the aspectual properties of the thing it represents; this here is sort of the opposite: leaving the writing as perfectly regular writing, but twisting its _content_ to maximise likeness with the concept it represents. If it weren't for the fact that _onomatopoeia_ has become limited to sound, it would be a good word, really.